# Phonegap - InAppBrowser - Cross Origin Policy

Tags: android, cross-domain, cordova, inappbrowser

I realize domain's require white listing in order to make cross domain calls within the actual Phonegap app, but does the InAppBrowser plugin also abide by these white listing rules?

Cordova 2.7.0 - Android

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily needed,

Check the `_self` description

> ```
> window.open( strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures])
>
> strWindowName:
> ```
>
> `"_self"` -> opens in the Cordova WebView if strUrl is in the
>   white-list, else it opens in the InAppBrowser
>
> `"_system"` -> always open in the system web browser
>
> `"_blank"` -> always open in the InAppBrowser